# Can't stop or view rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debian, webrick, google-chrome-os

When I close my terminal window running my Rails server, the server continues running in the background. I can't re-open the rails server and close it. Even quitting the terminal application isn't enough, I have to full restart my computer in order to stop the rails server.

Is there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should kill the server using ctrl+c, to stop the server.

```
  If not use this command to kill the port on which the your app is running,

   fuser -n tcp -k (port number)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pressing ctrl-c is the proper way to stop the server

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2014-04-08 21:14:42] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2014-04-08 21:14:42] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-11-22) [x86_64-linux]
[2014-04-08 21:14:42] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2677 port=3000
```

If you have accidentally closed the terminal you can check the process id in tmp/pid
then execute

```
kill 8976
```

where 8976 is the pid to terminate the process. Then you should be able to run your server again.

Happy coding :D

Answer (score 0):

```
ps aux | grep rails
```

See pid number for your rails server, then run this command

```
kill -9 pid
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows, you can delete the server PID file that is on your app file/tmp/pids and it will kill the server. To avoid having to do this, try hitting CTRL+c multiple times until the CMD tells shows that the server process was terminated.